# What is the meaning of "16 mile road" in this particular rap?

Tags: 8-mile

In the first rap battle between B-Rabbit (Eminem) and Lil' Tic (Proof), Lil' Tic makes a reference to a "16 mile road": What does he mean?

Here us the video of that scene from Youtube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 16 mile road refers to the actual [16 Mile Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roads_and_freeways_in_metropolitan_Detroit#16_Mile_Road) where white people are demographically predominant.

To understand what it means one needs to take a look at the remaining lyrics. The last two lines of that rap are

> So put ya hockey stick and baseball bat away
>
> Cause this here Detroit, 16 Mile road thataway, thataway

Let' break it down.

> So put ya hockey stick and baseball bat away

Lil’ Tic is using "hockey stick and baseball bat" as a metaphor (perhaps stereotyping) to represent white people and specifically B-Rabbit here.

> Cause this here Detroit,

this is Detroit which is our (black people's) area. Because Detroit is a [demographically black predominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._cities_with_large_African-American_populations#Cities_with_the_highest_percentage_of_Blacks_or_African_Americans) city.

> 16 Mile road thataway, thataway

and your (white people's*) area, 16 Mile road, is thataway - in the other direction, not here - meaning you don't belong here.

---

*[16 Mile Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_Parkway_(Detroit_area)) goes through following majors junctions where white people are demographically predominant.

- [Bloomfield Hills](http://www.city-data.com/city/Bloomfield-Hills-Michigan.html#mapOSM?mapOSM[zl]=14&mapOSM[c1]=42.57788&mapOSM[c2]=-83.24529&mapOSM[s]=races3&mapOSM[fs]=false)
- [Troy](http://www.city-data.com/city/Troy-Michigan.html#mapOSM?mapOSM[zl]=12&mapOSM[c1]=42.57888&mapOSM[c2]=-83.14775&mapOSM[s]=races3&mapOSM[fs]=false)
- [Sterling Heights](http://www.city-data.com/city/Sterling-Heights-Michigan.html#mapOSM?mapOSM[zl]=12&mapOSM[c1]=42.580965&mapOSM[c2]=-83.03033500000001&mapOSM[s]=races3&mapOSM[fs]=false)
- [Mount Clemens](http://www.city-data.com/city/Mount-Clemens-Michigan.html#mapOSM?mapOSM[zl]=13&mapOSM[c1]=42.59788&mapOSM[c2]=-82.878845&mapOSM[s]=races3&mapOSM[fs]=false)

Comment: You skip the line before calling him a tourist. Important context.